# Block search engines to find my CV? What does it mean?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I was wondering how this works:

> #### Search Engines
>
> Your CV is currently blocking all search engines.

Because I found that (in Google's Search Console) stackoverflow links to a website I'm an owner. Which is correct. I have a link in my CV to that website.

How does this blocking work? Google knows about the page and the content, but doesn't show it in search results?

Comment: All major legitimate search engines respect the robots.txt standard: http://www.robotstxt.org/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you block search engines, we add this meta tag to your public cv page.

[image]

Which instructs all the well meaning, legitimate search engines of the world to not surface your page in search results.